# Hide parent div with jQuery and show another

Tags: jquery

I have a container that has several divs with content. i need to be able to click "switch" element and hide this parent div and at the same time show new div that is hidden below. I thought of doing it with click event but I am not sure how to target the two divs.

```
$('.change').click(function() {
      $(this).parent("div").hide().next("div").show();
});


<div id="container">
   <div>
      old content abc <span class="change">switch</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      new content abc  
   </div>

   <div>
      old content 123 <span>switch</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      new content 123  
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine ^_^. look here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/VnSwk/

I would say make one change with the js:

```
$('.change').click(function() {
    $this = $(this)
    $(this).parent("div").hide().next("div").show().append($this);
});
$('#container').children().hide();
$($('#container').children()[0]).show();
```

Comment: that will just break if you keep switching :)

Comment: @cwolves. i know i see that he has to work on it. i gave a stepping stone ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Um, there's nothing wrong with that code.  It will make the first div hide, and the 2nd (new content abc) visible.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/nNuG6/1/

Answer (score 1):

I may be too late for this answer. All you need to do is have one button for the switch. If end is reached, it goes back to start.

```
var $cdiv = $('#container').find('div');
var i = 0;
$cdiv.hide();    
$('button').click(function() {
    $cdiv.hide();
    $cdiv.eq(i).show();
    $cdivlength >= i ? i++ : i=0;
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gE8Pv/2/