# Target div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have modified my code to streamline it a bit better. I need to be able to hide "old" span and show "new" one when "change" is clicked. I tried using siblings() but it does not appear to work. Am I missing something here:

```
$(".new").hide();

$('.change').click(function() {
    $(".new").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".old").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".new").show();
});

<div id="container">
  <div>
    <div class="switches">
        <span class="change">switch</span>
        <span class="go">go</span>
    </div>
    <span class="old">old content</span>
    <span class="new">new content</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="change">switch</span>
    <span class="old">old content</span>
    <span class="new">new content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

Please note that I have added another level of depth for my triggers placing it inside

```
<div class="switches">
```

Now I can't target the right div...

Comment: you JUST asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409886/hide-parent-div-with-jquery-and-show-another/5409980#5409980 since this one is SLIGHTLY different: `$(this).parent().find('.old').hide().end().find('.new').show()`

Comment: I have rewritten code and the previous one does not apply to this. It looks similar though, you're right.

Comment: I had to move my toggle one level deeper. How do i target appropriate divs now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.change').click(function() {
    $(".new").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".old").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".new").show();
});
```

You aren't listening to the right element, this should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
$('.editIco').click(function() {
    $(".new").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".old").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".new").show();
})
```

With:

```
$('.change').click(function() {
    $(".new").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".old").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".new").show();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think $(this).siblings refers to the children of the parent of the thing with the class, editIco.

Andy